# content-type request header

Tags: http-headers

I'm making an ajax call to a rest API and specified the following header an http post request.

```
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

My post body contains some japanese/chinese characters.

Now what my question is, do I need the encode the body of the post request with UTF-8 encoding or the browser takes care of encoding?

Comment: Note that `:` is required after `Content-Type:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your `Content-Type` header declares UTF-8 charset, then you *must* send the content in the UTF-8 encoding.

Although browsers sometimes "guess" or "fix" the encoding, you should never rely on this, as this is a very fragile logic that often fails to work properly.

If your Chinese/Japanese content was in a different encoding (like Shift-JIS), then you will have to convert the text with library like `iconv`.

Alternatively you could declare that other encoding in the header, but note that you can use only single encoding for all of the response body.  Converting everything to UTF-8 is usually the best solution.